# Comparing the file's existence from a file and in current directory using shell script

Tags: bash, unix

I have a file files.txt with content:

```
F1.txt
F2.txt
F3.txt
F4.txt
```

I need to read the file files.txt line by line, and check if it exists in the current directory, if it does, I need to append the date at the end of each of line of files.txt, so that the output should be

```
F1.txt16032017
F2.txt16032017
F3.txt16032017
F4.txt16032017
```

I have used following simple shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
DT=`date +%d%m%Y`
while IFS=read -r line
do 
if [ -f $line]
then
echo "$line$DT" > files.ok
else
echo "$line" > files.notok
fi
done < files.txt
```

It executes without any error, but does not provide expected output with date append. Can someone tell me if the file existence test is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your file write operator `>` which creates a *creates* a new file on every successful case, you need to have used the `>>` operator which *appends* to the existing file.

A much neater approach to your code would be to do

```
#!/bin/bash

dateToday="$(date +%d%m%Y)"

while IFS= read -r file; do
    [ -f "$file" ] && printf "%s\n"  "$file$dateToday" >> files.OK || printf "%s\n"  "$file" >> files.NOK
done < files.txt
```

What updates that I have made to improve the script,

1. Removed the outdated command substitution syntax using backticks `` and used the `$(..)` for running them.
2. Double-quoted the variables, lower-cased the local variables.
3. Fixed the file write operator from `>` to `>>`
4. Used a single line condition making use of the return code of the `test ([])` operator. The command after `&&` runs if the condition `[ -f "$file" ]` is successful and the command after `||` runs if the condition fails.

Comment: Thanks a lot Inian. It does work for me. I missed to add another point here. I was trying to append the date/timestamp of the file during its existence check in current directory. I used following code inside the while loop: DT= "$( ls -lrt $file | awk -F" " '{print $6$7$8}')".  Now it does not append the date in the "files.ok" file. Any advise.

Comment: Ok I got it now. I had to drop the space between =. Now it worked. Thanks for your help a lot Inian.